# How to make table responsive in wordpress? Best wordpress table plugin for free?

Tags: wordpress, datatables, css-tables, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

On my site https://afkarenacodes.com/afk-arena-codes-list/ I put a table, but it is not good responsive on mobile devices, Is there any way to perfectly make it responsive as it appears on web.

Answer (score 0):

TablePress Plugin allows you to easily create and manage responsive tables.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tablepress/